Removing a flat flex cable for re-use
I have an LCD display that I want to re-use. It is attached to the PCB via a flat flex cable, which I believe is ACF bonded:

Ideally I want to remove the cable intact, and then fit it to a socket instead of bonded to a PCB.
I've been having trouble finding information on how to do this. I am aware of G450 which is supposed to free ACF bonded cables, but can't find much information about its use for that purpose. Everything seems focused on cleaning up after removing the cable, with little concern for damaging it.
I have seen suggestions to apply Kapton tape and use heat, but I am worried that would melt the cable. I'm not sure how it was bonded in the first place, if heat was used or just adhesive.
How can I remove and re-use this cable in a socket? Or at least bond it to my own PCB.
Edit: 3M has a guide: https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/501881O/3mtm-anisotropic-conductive-film-adhesive-5363-rework-process.pdf?&fn=5363_ACF_6002969.pdf
It looks doable, probably the solvent method is the place to start as with only a basic heat gun and soldering iron it will be difficult to apply the recommended 150°C temperature. Also you need the solvent to clean it up anyway.
Still, I'd like to hear from anyone with experience, or other ideas/comments.
Edit: 99% IPA doesn't work.

I'd apply heat from the other side of the board.

What do you base that on?

I was able to remove it with my hot air rework gun set to 100°. Afterwards I was able to clean it up with IPA.
The cable is very thin for a ribbon. I think I will have to put some layers of another tape on it to stiffen and thicken it for a socket.
Heating from the bottom might not work, it has something like Kapton tape that mechanically bonds it to the PCB. I applied heat from the top.
The main issue with now is that the cable has a 1.5mm pitch, and nobody seems to make 1.5mm pitch FPC connectors.

Maybe I'm stating the obvious but if it's a one-off DIY then you could of course just solder thin wires to the pads after cleanup.

I don't think the pads will take solder, they are graphite/carbon. Like the pads used for membrane keys.
